# Is there a way to get Collection of a model and get only objects whose relationship rows exists?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have three models User, Post and Comment

```
User
  -id
Post
  -user_id
Comment
  -post_id
```

My table has issues, for example, some posts are not there or some user rows are not there.

How can I be able to get only comments that have a post_id which exists and it also has a user_id of the user which exists using a scope most preferably global scope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have set up the [relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many) in the models, you can get them using the `whereHas` method:

```
$commentsWithPostWhichHaveAUser = Comment::whereHas('Post', function($query){
    $query->has('User');
});
```

Comment: I tried this solution and I believe it works. But I have another issue tables were badly named for example in the above case instead of `posts` the table name is `post`. So I end up having an error that says Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'db_name.posts'. What do I do ?

Comment: @iamafasha Inside your post model you should set the attribute `$table=' post'`, see https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#table-names

Comment: that is already done. but it still uses the plural, I believe it's an issue with the version of laravel I am using 5.8

Comment: @iamafasha that should work in Laravel 5.8. How does your relationship method look inside your Comment model?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend that you first try to resolve this anomaly what happened in the database.
You could achieve it using nullable foreign id, and foreign key constraints.

If you use foreing key constraint it shall not happen that a model connected to a not existing model. You could set it null, all the foreign ids which does not exists, in the parent database.

Alternatively you could use this code:

```
   Comment::whereHas('post', function($q){
    $q->has('user');
   })->get();
```